# Maximum Email Body Size

Tags: email, html-email

I am not sure if this should be a question here or question on some stack overflow forum. If that is the case, please let me know if there is a way to move it there.

So I work on email templates in my organization. While looking at one requirement for new project, we realized that content of the body is going to be huge once this is deployed to production. However, we are not sure how "huge" is allowed? Is there some kind of maximum limit on how much content in Bytes you can send in HTML email?

Please note I am not talking about attachments here but the actual email body.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- GMail typically clips content at around 102kb as per Mailchimp's research around this [here](http://kb.mailchimp.com/delivery/deliverability-research/gmail-is-clipping-my-email)
- Based on @tadman [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42539707/maximum-email-body-size/42539774#comment72216692_42539774), it looks like the SMTP server can reject receipt of the message based on the [ESMTP SIZE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1870#section-6) attribute

Comment: Thanks. Yes this is what I came across as well. I guess my concern is more around email actually failing to get delivered due to large email body rather than gmail "not showing" the full email but truncating it saying "Click here to view full email" or somthing like that

Comment: This is a bit misleading. The full statement about GMail is: ‘Gmail clips emails that have a message size larger than 102KB, and hides the full content behind a “View entire message” link.’ So even if an email is bigger than 102 kB, the rest will still be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is going to vary based on the email provider. A quick google search about gmail yielded this: https://www.lifewire.com/message-and-attachment-size-limits-in-gmail-1172012

"Gmail processes messages up to 25 MB in size. This limit is applied to the sum of the message's text and the encoded attachment.Typically, encoding makes the size of the file grow slightly.Messages exceeding the limit sent to your Gmail account will bounce back to the sender. Messages larger than 25 MB that you try to send from Gmail will yield an error."

Your going to have to do research for each email provider that you want to support.

Comment: I believe this limit is for emails with attachments. I have been researching on google to find more about this and came across this article https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2011/11/maximum-file-size-for-html-email/. It says that maximum limit for HTML email for Gmail is set to 102 KBs.

Comment: @DotNetNewBie That is correct, the *content* size of the email is usually clipped at around 102kb. You can answer your own question with that I believe.

Comment: @DotNetNewBie Many mail servers will flat out reject emails beyond a certain size, the [ESMTP `SIZE` attribute](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1870) can describe this, but this size is the entire email, encoded, without regard to how much of that is attachment based. 102KB is Gmail's arbitrary "read more" cutoff, but larger emails are still accepted.

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical limit defined in the SMTP protocol for message BODY https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1870

It all depends on the client and server implementation you are using.

Comment: It probably also depends on all the intermediate MTAs, too.  Many will have policy limits to prevent resource abuse (based on total message size, rather than any individual part).

Answer (score -2):

Pixel size of an email is typically around 600 pixels with some going as wide as 700 pixels.

That being said you want to keep an email's size as **SMALL AS POSSIBLE** to make sure it is seen by as many people as possible. 500k is a good rule of thumb, and even 1 mb is fine. I have even stretched it to as much as 2 mb.

The reason for this is that MOST people nowadays read most of their emails on mobile devices.

Comment: The question size means the size in bytes, the text size, not the dimensions or pixels of email for styling, just read the question carefully, it is about the bytes, not styling pixels..
> "how much content in Bytes you can send in HTML email"